# Validate an email address is valid and came from a specific Domain

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Given an email address, say: bob@google.com

In Coldfusion, how can i validate that the email is from "google.com" and not another domain?

Comment: Are you asking about sending an email to the account to confirm that the email is valid, or simply checking everything after the @ sign against a list of 'ok' domains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here is the answer **in CFML** :)

```
<cfset email = "bob@google.com" />
<cfif ListLast(email, "@") EQ "google.com">
Horray!
</cfif>
```

**EDIT**

Specially for Amarghosh. We can do it this way, no worries:

```
<cfscript>
    email = "bob@google.com";
    if (ListLast(email, "@") == "google.com") {
        // here you go
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: +1 for answering in the correct language - btw, that's a funny syntax.

Comment: @Amarghosh Funny but fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for a specific domain, it might be easier to just use some string operations.

I don't know coldfusion, but something akin to

```
addr.lastIndexOf("@google.com")
```

If it's not -1, then it's from the domain you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(email.substring(email.indexOf("@") + 1) == "google.com")
    print("valid");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to compare the domain of an e-mail address?

```
listLast("bob@google.com","@") IS "google.com"
```

is one way to do it.